# how to serve html file used in react in server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

this is folder of code

[image]

I use node js and react to build a project I build design using react and controller to get data  how I can serve html file in server so when run node server.js it open html page that I created I try this in server. js

```
app.get('/english', function(req, res) {
    res.send(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
```

and when i run this route `localhost:3000/english` i got this

```
/home/projects/folder/folder2/myproject/index.html
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask You need to explain your question in more detail before it can be answered.

Comment: No. You need to provide your code at least [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Read the html file first. You could assign it to a variable first then before sending.

Comment: Or you could also use a view engine like handlebars or ejs

Comment: Can you give me example ?

Comment: var html = fs.readFileSync('./index.html', 'utf8'); res.end(html); This is not a good practice to use sync functions but just for example. :)

Comment: actually i use this app.get('/english', function(req, res) {
    res.send(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
and when i run this route localhost:3000/english i got this 
/home/projects/folder/folder2/myproject/index.html

Comment: I think you can't send `path.join(__dirname + '/index.html')` directly. You need to get the html code inside first.

Comment: ya index.html is not empty